# R: XML into dataframe problems with format

Tags: xml, r

I am not familiar with importing XML files into R.
I have looked into the existing questions regarding this topic but could not find one that seems to fit. I am thankful for your comments!

My problem is the following:
I have an XML file with the following structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<PublicationData>
    <Products numberOfProducts="2094">
        <Product terminationReason="" isSalePermission="false" soldoutDeadline="" exhaustionDeadline="" name="Résanol Trio " wNbr="6016" id="7034">
            <ProductInformation>
                <ProductCategory primaryKey="7282"/>
                <ProductCategory primaryKey="7282"/>
                <FormulationCode primaryKey="6486"/>
                <DangerSymbol primaryKey="6513"/>
                <DangerSymbol primaryKey="6509"/>
                <CodeS primaryKey="6145"/>
                <CodeS primaryKey="6117"/>
                <CodeS primaryKey="6039"/>
                <CodeS primaryKey="6057"/>
                <CodeS primaryKey="6066"/>
                <CodeS primaryKey="6106"/>
                <CodeS primaryKey="6076"/>
                <CodeS primaryKey="6088"/>
                <CodeR primaryKey="5977"/>
                <CodeR primaryKey="5943"/>
                <CodeR primaryKey="5945"/>
                <CodeR primaryKey="5948"/>
                <CodeR primaryKey="6020"/>
                <PermissionHolderKey primaryKey="10115"/>
                <Ingredient additionalTextPrimaryKey="" inGrammPerLitre="" inPercent="7.5">
                    <SubstanceType xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">ACTIVE_INGREDIENT</SubstanceType>
                    <Substance primaryKey="898"/>
                </Ingredient>
                <Ingredient additionalTextPrimaryKey="" inGrammPerLitre="" inPercent="40.0">
                    <SubstanceType xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">ACTIVE_INGREDIENT</SubstanceType>
                    <Substance primaryKey="338"/>
                </Ingredient>
                <Ingredient additionalTextPrimaryKey="" inGrammPerLitre="" inPercent="15.0">
                    <SubstanceType xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">ACTIVE_INGREDIENT</SubstanceType>
                    <Substance primaryKey="190"/>
                </Ingredient>
                <Indication expenditureTo="" expenditureForm="8.0" waitingPeriod="" dosageTo="" dosageFrom="0.5">
                    <Measure primaryKey="6518"/>
                    <ApplicationArea primaryKey="3"/>
                    <ApplicationComment primaryKey="868"/>
                    <Culture additionalTextPrimaryKey="" primaryKey="9953"/>
                    <Pest type="PEST_FULL_EFFECT" additionalTextPrimaryKey="" primaryKey="10506"/>
                    <Pest type="PEST_FULL_EFFECT" additionalTextPrimaryKey="6964" primaryKey="10508"/>
                    <Pest type="PEST_FULL_EFFECT" additionalTextPrimaryKey="" primaryKey="10507"/>
                    <Pest type="PEST_PARTIAL_EFFECT" additionalTextPrimaryKey="" primaryKey="10533"/>
                    <Obligation primaryKey="12317"/>
                    <Obligation primaryKey="11380"/>
                    <Obligation primaryKey="9156"/>
                    <Obligation primaryKey="9735"/>
                    <Obligation primaryKey="9906"/>
                </Indication>
            </ProductInformation>
        </Product>
```

I am trying to extract the information in the "ProductInformation" Node and tried

```
xmlfile<-xmlParse("filepath")
relevant<-xpathApply(xmlfile,"//*/Products/Product")
relevant2<-sapply(relevant,xmlValue)
```

Which just gives me something like

```
[1] "ACTIVE_INGREDIENTACTIVE_INGREDIENT"                                                                                                      
[...] "ACTIVE_INGREDIENT"                                                                                                                       
[2094] "ACTIVE_INGREDIENT"
```

Using instead

```
relevant2<-sapply(relevant,xmlAttrs)
```

If was also not able to extract the information.

The answer to my problem is probably obvious but I cannot figure the answer out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this, but it lead to the same result:                                                                                                [[2093]]
 ProductInformation 
"ACTIVE_INGREDIENT" 

[[2094]]
 ProductInformation 
"ACTIVE_INGREDIENT" . Is there any other way how I can possibly access the information? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I meant `xpathApply(xmlfile, "//*/Products/Product/*", getChildrenStrings)`. Does this get you the results?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It gives the relevant nodes, but not the information contained:                                                                                              [[2093]]
    ProductCategory     ProductCategory     FormulationCode        DangerSymbol        DangerSymbol               CodeS 
                 ""                  ""                  ""                  ""                  ""                  ""      DangerSymbol        DangerSymbol               CodeS 
                 ""                  ""                  ""                  ""